# Exception encountered when calling layer and 'KerasTensor' object is not callable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, keras-layer

I'm newbie to reinforcement learning.
I'd like to see and understand the code that predicts Keras actor critic value, and then run it with some changes.

Example code: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/rl/actor_critic_cartpole.py

However, I ran into a problem when running it.

Below is the total error.

```
예외가 발생했습니다. TypeError
Exception encountered when calling layer "custom_model" "f"(type CustomModel).
'KerasTensor' object is not callable
Call arguments received by layer "custom_model""f"(type CustomModel):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 10, 10), dtype=float32)
  File "C:\Users\cglab\Desktop\Match3\Model.py", line 19, in call
    common = self.common(inputs)
TypeError: 'KerasTensor' object is not callable
```

Here is the code

```
import tensorflow as tf

from keras import layers

class CustomModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_hidden, max_x, max_y, n_tile_type):
        super(CustomModel, self).__init__()
        self.inputs = layers.Input(shape=(max_y, max_x))
        self.common = layers.Dense(num_hidden, activation="relu")(self.inputs)
        tf.debugging.assert_shapes([(self.inputs, (tf.TensorShape([None, 10, 10])))]) #not assert
        self.x_probs = layers.Dense(max_x, activation="softmax")(self.common)
        self.y_probs = layers.Dense(max_y, activation="softmax")(self.common)
        self.tile_prob = layers.Dense(n_tile_type, activation="softmax")(self.common)
        self.critic = layers.Dense(1)(self.common)

    def call(self, inputs):
        tf.debugging.assert_shapes([(inputs, (tf.TensorShape([None, 10, 10])))]) #not assert

        common = self.common(inputs) ##Error
        x_probs = self.x_probs(common)
        y_probs = self.y_probs(common)
        tile_prob = self.tile_prob(common)
        critic = self.critic(common)

    return [x_probs, y_probs, tile_prob, critic]

#Initialize and call

model = CustomModel(256, max_x, max_y, max_tile_type)

state = np.full((self.max_y, self.max_x), -1)
state = tf.convert_to_tensor(state, dtype=tf.float32)
state = tf.expand_dims(state, 0)

x_probs, y_probs, tile_probs, critic_value = model(state)
```

I need help. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to recreate your code with demo variables, the primary problem is you're supposed to put the return statement in the `call` method of the `class CustomModel`. That's why it's throwing the exception as `TypeError: 'KerasTensor' object is not callable` because your `CustomModel` class is not returning a proper tensor object. here's the corrected one:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class CustomModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_hidden, max_x, max_y, n_tile_type):
        super(CustomModel, self).__init__()
        self.common = layers.Dense(num_hidden, activation="relu")
        self.x_probs = layers.Dense(max_x, activation="softmax")
        self.y_probs = layers.Dense(max_y, activation="softmax")
        self.tile_prob = layers.Dense(n_tile_type, activation="softmax")
        self.critic = layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs):
        common = self.common(inputs)
        x_probs = self.x_probs(common)
        y_probs = self.y_probs(common)
        tile_prob = self.tile_prob(common)
        critic = self.critic(common)

        return [x_probs, y_probs, tile_prob, critic]

# Initialize and call
max_x = 10
max_y = 10
max_tile_type = 5
model = CustomModel(256, max_x, max_y, max_tile_type)

state = np.full((max_y, max_x), -1)
state = tf.convert_to_tensor(state, dtype=tf.float32)
state = tf.expand_dims(state, 0)

x_probs, y_probs, tile_probs, critic_value = model(state)

# Print shapes of the outputs for verification
print("x_probs shape:", x_probs.shape)
print("y_probs shape:", y_probs.shape)
print("tile_probs shape:", tile_probs.shape)
print("critic_value shape:", critic_value.shape)
```

The output is as follows:

```
x_probs shape: (1, 10, 10)
y_probs shape: (1, 10, 10)
tile_probs shape: (1, 10, 5)
critic_value shape: (1, 10, 1)
```

I've also made some other adjustments. You don't need the unnecessary `self.inputs` layer and the `tf.debugging.assert_shapes` statements, as they are not necessary in this context. Also I properly instantiated the `self.common` layer with the `__init__` method.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have one more question. 'self.x_probs = layers.Dense(max_x, activation="softmax")' this code If the input shape is (1,10,10) and max_x = 10 shouldn't the output shape be 1D? Why is the size of the output return (1,10,10) instead of 1D? – 
donghyunlee
 2 mins ago

Comment: Nah, the dense layer would return a 2D shape as it's taking a 2D input.  The tensor has a shape of (1, 10, 10), meaning: the first dimension represents the batch size, which is 1 in this case. the second dimension represents the number of rows (Y coordinates), which is 10 and the third dimension represents the number of columns (X coordinates), which is also 10.

Comment: you can print the input and output shape layer-wise and check the shapes

Answer (score 2):

A `Layer` is callable, and calling it with a `Tensor` will normally return another `Tensor`, which is not callable (update: the user can create custom `Layer`s that return other stuff, but for the basic ones such as the one in this question, the return values are not callable). More specifically, in `__init__()` we should just **create** the layers, and in `call()` we call them on actual input (that looked OK in the code):

```py
    def __init__(self, num_hidden, max_x, max_y, n_tile_type):
        super(CustomModel, self).__init__()
        self.inputs = layers.Input(shape=(max_y, max_x))
        self.common = layers.Dense(num_hidden, activation="relu")
        tf.debugging.assert_shapes([(self.inputs, (tf.TensorShape([None, 10, 10])))]) #not assert
        self.x_probs = layers.Dense(max_x, activation="softmax")
        self.y_probs = layers.Dense(max_y, activation="softmax")
        self.tile_prob = layers.Dense(n_tile_type, activation="softmax")
        self.critic = layers.Dense(1)
```

Note how the `(self.common)` and likes were removed.